# Scrapy returning None on querying by xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi so i am using srapy to scrape a website https://www.centralbankofindia.co.in and I am getting a response but on finding address by XPath I am getting None

```
    start_urls = [
    "https://www.centralbankofindia.co.in/en/branch-locator?field_state_target_id=All&combine=&page={}".format(
        i
    )
    for i in range(0, 5)
]
brand_name = "Central Bank of India"
spider_type = "chain"
# //*[@id="block-cbi-content"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/span[2]
# //*[@id="block-cbi-content"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/span[2]
# //*[@id="block-cbi-content"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/span[2]
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    """Parse response."""
    # print(response.text)
    for id in range(1, 11):
        address = self.get_text(
            response,
            f'//*[@id="block-cbi-content"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[{id}]/td[2]/div/span[2]',
        )
        print(address)

    def get_text(self, response, path):
    sol = response.xpath(path).extract_first()
    return sol
```

The span class for address in the website doesn't have a unique id, is that what is causing the problem?

Comment: it seems this page uses JavaScript to add elements but `scrapy` can't run JavaScript and you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. There is even module `scrapy-selenium`

Comment: or maybe tou should use less tags but more classes - and `//` to skip some tags. You should also check original HTML because some browers in DevTools may show `tbody` but HTML may not have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you created too complex `xpath`. You should skip some elements and use `//` instead.

Some browsers may show `tbody` in `DevTools` but it may not exists in HTML which `scrapy` gets from server so better always skip it.

And you could use `extract()` instead of `tr[{id}]` and `extract_first()`

This xpath works for me.

```py
all_items = response.xpath('//*[@id="block-cbi-content"]//td[2]//span[2]/text()').extract()
        
for address in all_items:
    print(address)
```

BTW: I used `text()` in `xpath` to get address without HTML tags.

---

Full working code.

You can put all in one file and run it as `python script.py` without creating `project`.

It saves results in `output.csv`.

In `start_urls` I set only link to first page because `parse()` searchs  link to next page in HTML - so it can get all pages instead of `range(0, 5)`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    start_urls = [
        # f"https://www.centralbankofindia.co.in/en/branch-locator?field_state_target_id=All&combine=&page={i}"
        # for i in range(0, 5)
        
        # only first page - links to other pages it will find in HTML
        "https://www.centralbankofindia.co.in/en/branch-locator?field_state_target_id=All&combine=&page=0"
    ]
    
    name = "Central Bank of India"
    
    def parse(self, response):
        print(f'url: {response.url}')
        
        all_items = response.xpath('//*[@id="block-cbi-content"]//td[2]//span[2]/text()').extract()
        
        for address in all_items:
            print(address)
            yield {'address': address}

        # get link to next page
        
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@rel="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        
        if next_page:
            print(f'Next Page: {next_page}')
            yield response.follow(next_page)
            
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```